# What is this: a dual CAP?

Tags: capacitor, tantalum

I am trying to figure this cap out and locate a new one. It says 107K and 10K on it. Is is polarized ? what is it and where do i find one  ?

[image]

Comment: According to this web page, that one is called "Clyde":  http://sydlexia.com/imagesandstuff/pacman/ghosts.png

Comment: @Neil can you post a picture of it? Although capacitor codes come in a ###X format, the numbers 6 and 7 is never used on the third digit or multiplier. 107K is an invalid code.

Comment: @shimofuri: ??? Kemet and other manufacturers of tantalum and large ceramic capacitors do it all the time. "107" = 10 * 10^7 pF = 100uF capacitors

Comment: I don't know why the upper "K" is there; it doesn't correspond to Kemet's capacitor marking specification. But the lower K with the bars is the Kemet trademark, and if the upper K weren't there, the rest of the markings would match the Kemet capacitor marking specification.

Comment: Aha, here we go: the upper "K" indicates a special order 10% tolerance. If you look at the image from the Kemet catalog I posted, it says "CAPACITANCE TOLERANCE M = ±20% (K -- 10% Special Order Only)". The K is a standard capacitor code for 10% tolerance (J = 5%, M = 20%)

Comment: @JasonS I commented before a picture was posted. I was asking for a pic as xx6/xx7 is never used for small value ceramic capacitor and the second 10K marking is also of no help. Please see this link for the standards on capacitor markings: http://wiki.xtronics.com/index.php/Capacitor_Codes.

Answer (score 12):

It's a 10V 100uF 3-leaded tantalum capacitor from Kemet (T396 series -- see [Kemet's website](http://www.kemet.com/datasheets&T350A105K035AT) and [TTI](http://www.ttiinc.com/object/kemet_tantalum_th_dip)). The "K" with the bars above and below is a trademark of Kemet. The yellow encapsulation and the stencil font of the numbering are consistent with Kemet capacitors as well, but I can't say for sure whether other companies have copied them.

Their circuit diagram shows two ground leads, presumably to reduce ESR and inductance (although it seems like if you really want to reduce ESR and inductance you should use a surface mount capacitor)

Aha, this is what they say about the three-lead design:

> The three-leaded design (the anode is in the center) enables operators to insert the capacitors into printed circuit boards correctly without having to visually determine polarity. This timesaving device also eliminates board damage that may result from incorrect insertion.

[image]

Comment: "*enables operators to incert (sic) the capacitors into printed circuit boards correctly without having to visually determine polarity*". This can't be serious. Components are made to be mounted by a pick and place machine, which doesn't need to visually determine polarity.

Comment: Perhaps you are forgetting that through-hole components come from an age when pick-and-place machines were less common. The "incert" misspelling was my fault, not Kemet's, and I have corrected it.

Comment: Manually inserting a 3-pin capacitor takes longer than a 2-pin part. So more expensive.

Comment: I'm not defending that it's a good design, or that it's more cost effective, I'm just trying to explain why Kemet might have justified the use of such a component.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, the penalty for installing tantalum capacitors backwards is very bad -- they can self-ignite and damage the board they are installed on.

Comment: It remains a strange argument. It's more costly like I said, and common (2-pin) capacitors have different length leads to ensure proper mounting.

Comment: So... what are we arguing about exactly? I believe I have identified the part that Neil posted in his question. I don't use tantalum capacitors in my designs and would be unlikely to ever want to use this 3-legged "feature" myself.

Comment: Maybe there were automatic trough-hole insertion machines? Tantalum caps are usually symmetric so it would be difficult for the machine to insert them in correct orientation. I have a CGA card that uses these capacitors.

Comment: @JasonS I had tantalums ignite on me the first few times I used them, until I realised that, unlike all other polarised caps in the world, they mark the *high* voltage side. Tut.

Answer (score 6):

<s>Nope, I think stevenvh is right. It's a ceramic resonator.</s>

OK, I have changed my mind again after seeing [Jason's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/29858).  This is the reason Murata give for their three terminal capacitor.

[image: Three terminal capacitor]

[According to Murata](http://www.murata.com/products/emc/knowhow/pdf/20to22.pdf), they are used when you want a decoupling capacitor with greatly reduced effective series inductance.

Answer (score 4):

This looks much like the dual capacitors found in [this discussion thread](http://www.electro-tech-online.com/general-electronics-chat/93599-capacitor-3-legs.html).

Here's a picture:

[image]

I would argue that they're <strike>non-polarized</strike> <strike>ceramic</strike> capacitors.

Comment: I would tend to agree with this, it even has the things labeled with C1 and (presumably) C2, though I never did see these things before personally.

Comment: They're tantalums, not ceramics, and they're not dual capacitors; they have 3 leads. But the ones you posted a picture of are from the same series: they are Kemet 47uF and 33uF tantalum capacitors from their T398 series. The K with the bars is a giveaway.

Comment: @JasonS Appropriate strikethrough applied.

Comment: well... technically they *are* polarized capacitors, it's just that the "+" terminal is in the middle and the two "-" terminals are at the ends. But +1 for the picture because having two photos (and three capacitors) to find a pattern from, was much easier than just the one posted above in the question. Thanks!

Comment: noted. and struck.

Answer (score 2):

From the three pins I'd say a **ceramic resonator**, and then the 107K reminds me of the 10.7MHz intermediate frequency in FM receivers. Resonators have their frequency as marking. So probably a 10.7MHz resonator. (Though in receivers crystals are more used than resonators, because they're more precise and more stable)